# Broadcast Receiver within a Service

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am trying to start up a `BroadcastReceiver` within a `Service`. What I am trying to do is have a background running `service` going that collects incoming text messages, and logs incoming phone calls. I figured the best way to go about this is to have a `service` running that incorporates a broadcast receiver that can catalog either.

How do i go about doing this? I already have my service up and running.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

as your service is already setup, simply add a broadcast receiver in your service:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
        //action for sms received
      }
      else if(action.equals(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)){
           //action for phone state changed
      }     
   }
};
```

in your service's `onCreate` do this:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
filter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
filter.addAction("your_action_strings"); //further more
filter.addAction("your_action_strings"); //further more

registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

and in your service's `onDestroy`:

```
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

and you are good to go to receive broadcast for what ever filters you mention in `onCreate`. Make sure to add any permission if required. for e.g.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Comment: Ive noticed I cannot pass data by intent.setData(myUri) while sending sendBroadcas(intent) and braoadcastReceiver doesn't work in that case, is it right?

Comment: I am little confuse about the service life-cycle  when it has BroadcastReceiver  (in my case download BroadcastReceiver)

Comment: @waqaslam Did you set this BroadcastReceiver in your Manifest?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No, you don't need to  register such receivers in manifest.

Comment: @waqaslam Your code uses an IntentFilter in the Service's onCreate() and registers the receiver.  Further below though you mention filtering in "onStartCommand"  Did you mean to say in "onCreate" or am I missing something?

Comment: @AJW Thanks for pointing out. It was a mistake which is fixed now :)

Comment: @waqaslam  I have a similar question listed here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520219/android-how-to-fix-broadcastreceiver-in-jobintentservice  Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: Hey i wanna ask if i  define BroadcastReceiver in Service not in mainactivity, will it will consume more battery , because there are two process are running for single app.. Or it will be ok my app will consume same amount of battery and ram in a device..

Comment: @SayyedRizwan Your service and BroadcastReceiver will run under same process and most probably same thread (unless you create a new one). Battery consumption depends on how you have defined your thread (background/Foreground) and the amount of broadcasts coming in.

Comment: @waqaslam can you solve this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63350856/5359340

Comment: I am not receiving any(!) intents in my broacast receiver. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 25):

The better pattern is to create a standalone `BroadcastReceiver`. This insures that your app can respond to the broadcast, whether or not the `Service` is running. In fact, using this pattern may remove the need for a constant-running `Service` altogether.

Register the `BroadcastReceiver` in your Manifest, and create a separate class/file for it.

Eg:

```
<receiver android:name=".FooReceiver" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When the receiver runs, you simply pass an `Intent` (`Bundle`) to the `Service`, and respond to it in `onStartCommand()`.

Eg:

```
public class FooReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // do your work quickly!
        // then call context.startService();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I want the broadcast to be within the life cycle of the service, so that the app is only querying messages/phone calls according to the service time line. Does this method enable that? it looks like you have set it up so the reception of the broadcast sets off the service.

Comment: This implementation would start the `Service` if it was not already running, or pass a new `Intent` if it is (for retrieval in `onStartCommand`). If you only want it to run when the `Service` is live, you could programmatically enable/disable the `Receiver` component through the `PackageManager`'s `setComponentEnabledSetting()`.

Comment: Waqas's answer may your best option, if you only want the `Receiver` alive when the `Service` is running.

Comment: If you don't have an Activity, it won't work for API 3.1 and higher: http://ashimita.blogspot.com.tr/2012/04/broadcast-receiver-change-in-flow-since.html

Comment: As of Android 3.1 the Android system excludes all receiver from receiving intents by default if the corresponding application has never been started by the user or if the user explicitly stopped the application via the Android menu. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: The problem is when you kill the application broadcast receiver will auto stop and app will not work after this.