# Do something when a phone call is received

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-toast

I am trying to create an application that will perform different functions when a call is received. To make a small working example, I have made my class extend `BroadcastReceiver` and I have tried to get a toast notification to show up.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Do something.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I have added this permission in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Incoming Call Interceptor">
    <receiver android:name="IncomingCallInterceptor">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

My test device is running Android 4.4.2. No toast notification ever shows up when someone is calling in.

Comment: Did you register the receiver in your manifest?

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the receiver that is defined in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. Maybe there's something wrong with how I have declared it?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code To `Monitor the state of the Phone`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class PhoneReceiver extends PhoneStateListener {
Context context;
public PhoneReceiver(Context context) {
this.context = context;
}
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, 
String incomingNumber) {
super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
Toast.makeText(context, "onCallStateChanged state=" + 
state + "incomingNumber=" + incomingNumber, 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
switch (state) {
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
Toast.makeText(context, "idle", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
break;
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
Toast.makeText(context, "ringing", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
break;
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
Toast.makeText(context, "offhook", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
break;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from a similar thread: [Incoming call broadcast receiver not working (Android 4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603400/incoming-call-broadcast-receiver-not-working-android-4-1?rq=1)

> You must manually start an activity from your application before the
>   broadcast receivers starts to work as of Android 3.0.