# How to receive Broadcasts when app is off?

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-screen, android-intentservice

How can I make an app respond to `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` broadcasts even when the app is off?

I have been reading about [alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) and `IntentService` but I am not sure what the best practice is.

I am trying to make an app that takes pictures whenever the screen is unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

Register your `BroadcastReceiver` in a service.

From [Broadcast Receiver within a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092134/broadcast-receiver-within-a-service)