# BroadcastReceiver in Service Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to add a `BroadCastReciver` in a service. The `BroadCastReceiver` listens to phone calling. My problem is that the broadcast doesn't work in service (when I run the app it worked but when I go out of my app it didn't work).

**MainActiviy.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstService.class));

  }
}
```

**PhoneStateBrodcastRecevier.java**:

```
public class PhoneStateBrodcastRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
      TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      MyPhoneStateListener myPhoneStateListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(context);
      telephonyManager.listen(myPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    } catch (Exception e){}
  }
}
```

**FirstService.java**:

```
public class FirstService extends Service  {

  BroadcastReceiver myreciReceiver;

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    myreciReceiver=new PhoneStateBrodcastRecevier();
    IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    registerReceiver(myreciReceiver, intentFilter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.d("ddddddd", "start");

  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("ddddddd", "finish");
  }
}
```

And my **manifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateBrodcastRecevier">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".FirstService"/>
</application>
```

Comment: In your `Service` class, override `onStartCommand()` too and return `START_STICKY` from it.

Comment: I did that.but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your target is to listen for phone state changes in the `Service` class itself. You can try to define it internally within the `Service`. This will decrease resource usage too as the system is not burdened with handling the lifecycle of another component. In your `Service`:

```
private final PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            // Call receive state 
            if (state != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                // Do something
            } 
        } 
    };
```

Then you can register it to listen as (probably in `onStartCommand()`):

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

And then unregister it from listening in `onDestroy()` (or whenever you are done):

```
mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```

Comment: thanks.it's working very well.but where is my code problem that it didn't work?

Comment: @ABOLFAZLSHARIFI ... I'm having trouble understanding: `intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    registerReceiver(myreciReceiver, intentFilter);`...where are you initialising  `myreciReceiver`?

Comment: in the onCreate():     `myreciReceiver=new PhoneStateBrodcastRecevier();`

Comment: @ABOLFAZLSHARIFI Yeah, i don't believe thats the right way of registering for a receiver that also has an entry in the manifest

Comment: and this link was helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092134/broadcast-receiver-within-a-service

Comment: @ABOLFAZLSHARIFI Yeah...thats almost exactly to what I did above :)

Answer (score 0):

**Do something when the phone rings**

**Solution**

This can be achieved by implementing a Broadcast Receiver and listening for a TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED action.

**Discussion**

If you want to do something when the phone rings you have to implement a broadcast receiver which listens for the TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED intent action. This is a broadcast intent action indicating that the call state (cellular) on the device has changed.

1. Create a class IncomingCallInterceptor which extends BroadcastReceiver.
2. Override the onReceive method to handle incoming broadcast messages.
3. The EXTRA_STATE intent extra in this case indicates the new call state.
4. If (and only if) the new state is RINGING, a second intent extra EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER provides the incoming phone number as a String.
5. We extract the number information from the EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER intent extra.

Note: Additionally you can act on a state change to OFFHOOK or IDLE when the user picks up the phone or ends/rejects the phone call respectively.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {                                  

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {                                         
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);                        
    String msg = "Phone state changed to " + state;

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {                                   
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);  
        msg += ". Incoming number is " + incomingNumber;

        // TODO This would be a good place to "Do something when the phone rings" <img src="http://androidlabs.org/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_wink.gif" alt=";-)" class="wp-smiley"> 

    }

    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

6. We have to register our IncomingCallInterceptor as a  within the  element in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
7. We register an 'intent-filter'…
8. and an action value which registers our receiver to listen for TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast messages.
9. Finally we have to register a  so we are allowed to listen to phone state changes.

   ```
   <receiver android:name="IncomingCallInterceptor">                  
       <intent-filter>                                                   
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>   
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```

Comment: this doesn't work when the app is killed or it's not in the background. Doesn't work for Android 6,7,8,9,10